# how to replace &amp; from id in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mvc 4 project. Its a site showing data in the form of table with many a link. I am using

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditReport", "phed", New With {.rpid = item.id,.returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery}, New With {Key .Class = "ico edit"})%>
```

My reoute.config is

```
routes.MapRoute( _
           name:="Default", _
           url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
           defaults:=New With {.controller = "phed", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
       )
```

It shows a link as

```
example.com/phed/EditReport?rpid=2&returnUrl=phed
```

How can i route my request like

```
example.com/phed/EditReport?rpid=2/returnUrl=phed
```

I want to replace this '&' Ampersand in id with slash `/` or any other character?

Comment: You can't. & is what's used to separate components of the querystring. What you're asking fundamentally breaks the parsing of the querystring.... . ..

Comment: can you give us an example of a website that uses such URLs?

Answer (score 0):

No need to change route, just pass url llok like:

```
example.com/phed/EditReport/2/returnUrl=phed
```

for that code like :

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditReport", "phed", New With {.id= item.id,.returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery}, New With {Key .Class = "ico edit"})%>
```

Comment: Its not working. I want to change the '&' used in id for different values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Note tested

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditReport", "phed", New With {.rpid = UrlHelper.Encode(item.id+"\\returnUrl="+Request.Url.PathAndQuery)}, New With {Key .Class = "ico edit"})%>
```